# Docker , ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported

Tags: python, scrapy-splash

[Click here to see Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIGzh.png) I am following the instructions for installing python scrapy-splash and at the last step when I try to run the scrapinghub/splash at local host port , it throws an error of 'Running as root without' as shown in the screenshot.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, those issues are gone by exporting this variable

```
export QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX=1
```

Comment: so 
docker run -p 5023:5023 -p 8050:8050 -p 8051:8051 -env QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX=1 scrapinghub/splash